# compare 'in the eye of' vs 'in the eyes of'

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between 'in the eye of' vs 'in the eyes of'? In the eye of the beholder. In the eyes of him.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

"Beauty is in the eye of the beholder" is a set phrase which apparently originated in an 1878 novel. The author, Margaret Hungerford, chose to write *eye* in the singular.

I think most of us would use *in the eyes of X* to mean *from X's point of view.*

Comment: Good answer - but there does seem to me to be a pattern determining whether singular or plural is used. Compare "My grandson has an eye for the girls", and "In my eyes the lockdown is essential to protect life". Don't we use singular "eye" when we are speaking of something instinctive, but plural when it is something more considered? Or am I making too much of the difference?

Comment: @WS2 I agree "**the eye**" is probably synecdoche = the perception; the opinion; **an** eye" = a dedicated perception; a keen perception. Compare, "He kept one eye on the clock and the other on his prisoner."

Comment: Thanks. May I say that use singular for sth abstract and plural for sth concrete?

Comment: @feynman I think it's slightly different to that. Saying "in my eyes - this should happen" simply means "in my opinion...*. But "having an eye for..." or "something being in the eye of the beholder" etc is a more metaphorical sense. But it is not simply a question of whether "eye" is singular or plural, but in the structure around it.